# Golang socket.io server is malfunctioning for some reason

Tags: android, go, socket.io

After making some test [Golang and Android Kotlin code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76602152/10464730) to try out socket.io, I copied those code to my project's server and client app.

The only difference I did from the original code is run the socket server start as a `coroutine` because of necessity, as just calling `StartSocket` seems to be essentially a blocking function.
After the update, I tested if the code still works, and it does. The app can connect to the server and the app can emit to the server as well, and IIRC the app can also receive the emit from the server.

When I rebuild the app, the server shows that a client disconnects. Now, only the connection part works. Even the original app can't emit now, rebuilding the app doesn't seem to disconnect it anymore as well. And the client gets disconnected repeatedly again, but now it happens silently, like only a new connected message appears on the terminal. Before the repeated disconnection at least tells some reason why the the client disconnects.
If I `go run` the original code and pair it with the original app, everything works fine. I `go build` my project's code, but I doubt that should affect socket.io. I'm at my wits ends as to why everything (mostly) doesn't work anymore when I barely changed anything.

Here's my Golang code:

```
package helpers

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
)

var allowOriginFunc = func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
}
var (
    port = flag.Int("socket_server_port", 8000, "Socket sckServer port")
)

var sckServer *socketio.Server

const WARNING_TAG = "warning"
const ALERT_TAG = "alert"
const NAMESPACE = "notifications"
const SIMPLE_TAG = "simple"
const ROOM = "notif_room"

func StartSocket() {
    flag.Parse()

    sckServer = socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
        Transports: []transport.Transport{
            &polling.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
            &websocket.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
        },
    })

    sckServer.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())

        s.Emit("notice", "new user connected")
        return nil
    })

    sckServer.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        fmt.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("notice", "have "+msg)
    })

    sckServer.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        fmt.Println("socket error:", e)
    })

    sckServer.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        fmt.Println("closed", reason)
    })

    go sckServer.Serve()
    defer sckServer.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", sckServer)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))

    fmt.Printf("Socket sckServer serving at localhost:%d...\n", *port)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start socket sckServer: %v\n", err)
    }
}

func GetSocketSrv() *socketio.Server {
    return sckServer
}

func BroadcastToTag(tag string, payload string) {
    fmt.Printf("BroadcastToTag tag: %s, payload: %s\n", tag, payload)

    if sckServer != nil {
        broadcastStat := sckServer.BroadcastToNamespace(NAMESPACE, tag, payload)
        fmt.Printf("broadcastStat: %v\n", broadcastStat)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("sckServer = nil\n")
    }
}
```

And here's my Android Kotlin code:

```
import android.util.Log
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter
import java.net.ConnectException
import java.net.URISyntaxException

class SocketHelper {
    private lateinit var mSocket: Socket
    private val onAlertNotif =
        Emitter.Listener { args ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onAlertNotif args: ${args[0]}")
        }

    private val onWarningNotif =
        Emitter.Listener { args ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onWarningNotif args: ${args[0]}")
        }

    private val onSimpleNotif =
        Emitter.Listener { args ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onSimpleNotif args: ${args[0]}")
        }

    init {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://<local_ip>:8000/")
        }catch (e: ConnectException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket ConnExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket URISynExc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Exc: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }

    fun send(eventName: String, msg: String){
        mSocket.emit(eventName, msg)
    }

    fun open(){
        mSocket.on("alert", onAlertNotif)
        mSocket.on("warning", onWarningNotif)
        mSocket.on("simple", onSimpleNotif)

        mSocket.connect()
    }

    fun stop(){
        mSocket.off()
        mSocket.disconnect()
    }

    companion object{
        const val TAG = "SocketHelper"
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val socketHelper = SocketHelper()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        socketHelper.open()
    }
    
     override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        socketHelper.stop()
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

As an update, I'll also share the main.go from the server side as it might be helpful to you guys:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    pb "github.com/<me>/<project_name>/api/proto/out"
    cmmHelpers "github.com/<me>/<project_name>/cmd/commons/helpers"
    "github.com/<me>/<project_name>/cmd/server/handlers"
    "github.com/<me>/<project_name>/cmd/server/helpers"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
)

func init() {
    cmmHelpers.DatabaseConnection()
}

var (
    tls      = flag.Bool("tls", true, "Connection uses TLS if true, else plain TCP")
    certFile = flag.String("cert_file", "", "The TLS cert file")
    keyFile  = flag.String("key_file", "", "The TLS key file")
    port     = flag.Int("port", 50051, "The server port")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", *port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    var opts []grpc.ServerOption
    if *tls {
        if *certFile == "" {
            *certFile = "service.pem"
        }

        if *keyFile == "" {
            *keyFile = "service.key"
        }

        creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(*certFile, *keyFile)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to generate credentials: %v", err)
        }

        opts = []grpc.ServerOption{grpc.Creds(creds)}
    }

    mServ := grpc.NewServer(opts...)

    fmt.Println("gRPC server running ...")

    //some gRPC related boiler plate

    log.Printf("Server listening at %v", lis.Addr())

    go helpers.StartSocket()

    if err := mServ.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve : %v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found an answer, but it's the destructive kind. I ditched `socket.io` altogether and used what the built-in `net` package have. I'll just figure out how to implement those fancy features `socket.io` have later on if needed. Here's what the code looks like:

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

var (
    SOCKET_PORT   = flag.Int("socket_server_port", 9001, "Socket sckServer port")
    HOST          = flag.String("host name", "localhost", "server host name")
    socketConnArr = make(map[string]net.Conn)
)

func StartSocket() {
    listen, err := net.Listen(TYPE, fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *SOCKET_PORT))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("conn err: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer listen.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Socket sckServer serving at localhost:%d...\n", *SOCKET_PORT)

    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("accept err: %s", err)
            continue
        }
        socketConnArr[conn.RemoteAddr().String()] = conn

        fmt.Printf("socket client on: %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())

        go connWrite(conn, "socket server ack")
        go connRead(conn)
    }
}

func connRead(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    bytesRead, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("req err: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes: %s", bytesRead, string(buffer[:bytesRead]))
}

func connWrite(conn net.Conn, message string) {
    fmt.Println("Sending")
    conn.Write([]byte("\n")) //for some reason, this is very important
    conn.Write([]byte(message))
    conn.Write([]byte("\n"))
}
```

Then on the android side:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var response = ""

    try {
        socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
        writer = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
        reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))

        writer.println(socketInitMsg)
        writer.flush()

        while (true) {
            if (reader.readLine() != null) {
                response = reader.readLine()
                Log.i(SocketHelper.TAG, "response: $response")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(SocketHelper.TAG, "err1: " + e.localizedMessage)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(SocketHelper.TAG, "err11: " + e.localizedMessage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you do not have a concurrency issue: Since you are running the socket server as a Go routine, it might be terminating prematurely due to the lifecycle of the main function it is being launched from.
Ensure the `main` function does not terminate before the server is done handling all connections.
In the provided `main.go` code, you have `go helpers.StartSocket()` called just before starting the gRPC server. If the gRPC server closes (either due to error or program termination), the `StartSocket` goroutine may also get terminated.
See also "[Starting a socket server interferes with the gRPC/http client server communication Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613844/6309)"

And, as usual, do check your errors! There might be an error occurring either on the server side or the client side that is not being properly caught.

- In your Kotlin code, you are currently only catching `ConnectException` and `URISyntaxException`. It would be better to also catch a generic `Exception` as a fallback, as other unanticipated exceptions could occur.
- In your Go code, `sckServer.Serve()` might return an error that should be handled or logged.
- The `BroadcastToTag` function could check whether the broadcast was successful and handle or log any error that might have occurred. However, it seems like [`BroadcastToNamespace` function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io#Server.BroadcastToNamespace) does not return an error in its current implementation in the `go-socket.io` library.

Or, add error values: In the `GetSocketSrv` function, returning an error when `sckServer` is `nil` would be a better practice as it indicates that the socket server has not been initialized. This allows the caller to handle this situation appropriately instead of risking a panic. For instance, if `BroadcastToTag` is called before `StartSocket` or after the socket server is closed, `sckServer.BroadcastToNamespace` will cause a panic because `sckServer` is `nil`.

For improving error handling and better managing your goroutines' lifecycles, your code could include those updates:

```golang
    package helpers

    import (
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "sync"

        socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
        "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
        "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
        "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
        "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
    )

    var allowOriginFunc = func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }
    var (
        port = flag.Int("socket_server_port", 8000, "Socket sckServer port")
    )

    var sckServer *socketio.Server
    var wg sync.WaitGroup  // WaitGroup to manage goroutines' lifecycle

    // Constants, as before
    //...

    func StartSocket() {
        flag.Parse()

        sckServer = socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
            Transports: []transport.Transport{
                &polling.Transport{
                    CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
                },
                &websocket.Transport{
                    CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
                },
            },
        })

        // Event handlers, as before
        //...

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()  // When this goroutine finishes, mark one job as done
            sckServer.Serve()
        }()
        wg.Add(1)  // We have one job running

        defer func() {
            sckServer.Close()  // Make sure to close the server when the function exits
            wg.Wait()  // Wait for all jobs to finish
        }()

        // HTTP handlers, as before
        //...

        fmt.Printf("Socket sckServer serving at localhost:%d...\n", *port)

        err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port), nil)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to start socket sckServer: %v\n", err)
        }
    }

    func GetSocketSrv() (*socketio.Server, error) {
        if sckServer == nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Socket server is not initialized")
        }

        return sckServer, nil
    }

    // BroadcastToTag function, as before
    //...
```

For the `main.go`:

```golang
    package main

    import (
        // Imports, as before
        //...
    )

    // Initializations, as before
    //...

    func main() {
        flag.Parse()

        lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", *port))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
        }

        var opts []grpc.ServerOption
        if *tls {
            // Certificate and key file handling, as before
            //...
        }

        mServ := grpc.NewServer(opts...)

        fmt.Println("gRPC server running ...")

        // gRPC related boilerplate, as before
        //...

        log.Printf("Server listening at %v", lis.Addr())

        go func() {
            if err := helpers.StartSocket(); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to start socket server: %v", err)
            }
        }()

        if err := mServ.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to serve : %v", err)
        }
    }
```

Please replace "Imports, as before" and "gRPC related boilerplate, as before" comments with your original code.

---

> I already replaced those code with something that is using the much simpler net library

A simple TCP server/client implementation using [Go's `net` package](https://pkg.go.dev/net) for the server side and [Kotlin's `Ktor` library](https://ktor.io/) for the client side could be (without fully reproducing all the socket.io features, especially the ones related to namespaces and broadcast):

**Go server:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    fmt.Printf("Serving %s\n", c.RemoteAddr().String())
    for {
        netData, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        temp := strings.TrimSpace(string(netData))
        if temp == "STOP" {
            break
        }

        fmt.Println(temp)
        c.Write([]byte("Received data: " + temp + "\n"))
    }
    c.Close()
}

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":5000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start server: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        go handleConnection(c)
    }
}
```

The Go server will listen for incoming connections on TCP port 5000.
Upon receiving a connection, it will create a new goroutine to handle that connection independently of others.
It will then read the incoming data line by line, print it, and echo it back to the client with a "`Received data:`" prefix.

**Kotlin client:**

```kotlin
import io.ktor.network.sockets.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val socket = aSocket(Dispatchers.IO).tcp().connect(InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5000))

    val input = socket.openReadChannel()
    val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

    output.writeUTF8Line("Hello, Server!")
    val response = input.readUTF8Line()
    println("Server said: '$response'")

    output.writeUTF8Line("STOP")
    socket.close()
}
```

The Kotlin client will connect to the server, send a greeting message, wait for the response, print it, and then send a "STOP" message before closing the connection.
This code uses Kotlin coroutines and [Ktor's `aSocket` method](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-network/io.ktor.network.sockets/a-socket.html) to open the TCP connection.

Note: This code will work only if the server and client are running on the same machine. If they are on different machines, replace `"localhost"` with the server's IP address.

Remember to include Ktor library ([`ktor-network`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-network)) in your Kotlin dependencies:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-network:2.3.2'
}
```

Comment: I already replaced those code with something that is using the much simpler `net` library, but will check it out later

Comment: @rminaj Well done. I have edited the answer to include an alternative code based on the `net` package (and Kotlin `ktor-network` library)

Comment: Hmm, seems like your suggested changes for `socket.io` still doesn't work

Comment: @rminaj Do you have any details on what does not work?

Comment: Well, I already mentioned it on the question. On my test awhile ago, everything doesn't work anymore. Even the android client doesn't seem to be detected anymore, like it isn't able to connect to the socket server

Comment: @rminaj OK. Is my alternative example close to what you did with the `net` package?

Comment: Kinda, but I didn't use `bufio`.